# JPA Criteria query new column with SUM and Group By

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to make a new calculated col with criteria query like this SQL:

```
SELECT *, SUM(quantity) + SUM(pledged) as total, SUM(pledged) as pledged FROM stock_position GROUP BY partner_id, product_id
```

I need to get this result and set to another entity, so I need to use the alias total and map to entity. But I don't find a way to do this. I tried the code below.

```
    final CriteriaQuery<Stock> query = getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Stock.class);
    final Root<StockPosition> root = query.from(StockPosition.class);

    Expression<Double> quantity = getCriteriaBuilder().sum(root.<Double> get("quantity"));
    Expression<Double> pledged = getCriteriaBuilder().sum(root.<Double>get("pledged"));
    Expression<Double> total = getCriteriaBuilder().sum(quantity, pledged);

    query.select(total); //THIS GIVES ME ERROR
    query.groupBy(root.get("partner"), root.get("product"));
```

Of course the types are different, but I don't know how to map. Anyone can give a hand?

Thanks

Comment: it gives "error". Any particular error?

Comment: Error:(104, 30) java: incompatible types: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<java.lang.Double> cannot be converted to javax.persistence.criteria.Selection<? extends br.com.xxx.ejb.entity.stock.Stock>

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You want to sum up some values, but the query expects an entity of the class `Stock`.

The correct declaration would be as follows:

```
final CriteriaQuery<Double> query = getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Double.class);
```